# Class method can't access protected member "Error: identifier is undefined"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a very basic class that can't access it's own member.
I really have no understanding on why this doesn't work.

**header file:**

```
#ifndef SHAPE_1D_H
#define SHAPE_1D_H

#include "shape.h"

class Shape_1D : public Shape
{
public:
    // Constructor for the class
    Shape_1D();
};

#endif Shape_1D_H
```

**.cpp file:**

```
#include "shape.h"

// Constructor for the class
Shape::Shape(sf::VertexArray avVertices)
{       
    m_avVertices = avVertices;
}

// Draws the shape to the canvas
void draw(sf::RenderWindow window)
{    
    // ISSUE HERE - "Error: identifier "m_avVertices" is undefined"
    window.draw(m_avVertices, sf::RenderStates::Default);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using SFML, so I assume `Shape` eventually inherits `sf::Drawable`. So, you're trying to override `Shape::draw` by providing your own (member function).

`void draw(sf::RenderWindow window) {}` is not a member function definition if it's not defined in the class definition itself. You forgot something there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot `Shape::` in front of `draw`, ***if*** it should be a member function:

```
void Shape::draw(sf::RenderWindow window) {
     ^^^^^^^
```